# ApolloTestingModule flush mutiple times for watchQuery

Tags: unit-testing, apollo, apollo-client, angular-test, apollo-angular

I need to test a service that uses apollo client to fetch some data. It uses `watchQuery` in order to keep an open stream of values.

In the test I use `ApolloTestingModule` to `flush` the gql operation with test data. This works once, but I cannot test what happens when a new value is emitted (in other words I cannot flush more than once).

Is it actually possible to do it with ApolloTestingModule or would this fall into a feature request?